# Extract the name of the coeficients from regression Pr(>|t|) smaller than

Tags: r

I have the following regression

```
c<- glm (z[2:length(z)]~ Dxu10+Dxi10+Dxa10+Dxb10+Dxc10 +Dxd10+Dxe10+Dxf10)
```

I perform steepAIC for variable selection

```
st1<-stepAIC(c, scale = 0,direction = c("both"),trace = 1, keep = NULL, steps = 1000,    
use.start = FALSE,k = 2)

st2<-stepAIC(c, scale = 0,direction = c("forward"),trace = 1, keep = NULL, steps =  
1000,use.start = FALSE,k = 2)

st3<-stepAIC(c, scale = 0,direction = c("backward"),trace = 1, keep = NULL, steps =  
1000,use.start = FALSE,k = 2)
```

from which I obtain

```
summary(st1)$coefficients
               Estimate    Std. Error      t value                       Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.006993197279 0.00184524256  3.789852580 0.0001837029031540622766791038
Dxu10       -0.716501556217 0.07390750712 -9.694570743 0.0000000000000000002079180098
Dxi10        0.590876615303 0.10750681474  5.496178235 0.0000000857314345082674945844
Dxa10        0.844200223791 0.15866854150  5.320526778 0.0000002086989035634347231570
Dxb10        0.956284808429 0.21125669477  4.526648538 0.0000087898612369329389218398
Dxc10        1.078511870491 0.29582536479  3.645772131 0.0003164334473070340479974871
Dxd10        1.155441543282 0.56627553660  2.040422848 0.0422232960663285333824390477

summary(st2)$coefficients
               Estimate    Std. Error      t value                       Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.006993197279 0.00184524256  3.789852580 0.0001837029031540622766791038
Dxu10       -0.716501556217 0.07390750712 -9.694570743 0.0000000000000000002079180098
Dxi10        0.590876615303 0.10750681474  5.496178235 0.0000000857314345082674945844
Dxa10        0.844200223791 0.15866854150  5.320526778 0.0000002086989035634347231570
Dxb10        0.956284808429 0.21125669477  4.526648538 0.0000087898612369329389218398
Dxc10        1.078511870491 0.29582536479  3.645772131 0.0003164334473070340479974871
Dxd10        1.155441543282 0.56627553660  2.040422848 0.0422232960663285333824390477

summary(st3)$coefficients
               Estimate     Std. Error       t value                       Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.006993197279 0.001847746243  3.7847173574 0.0001876030310082417635643426
Dxu10       -0.716494801892 0.074007787774 -9.6813433213 0.0000000000000000002379841555
Dxi10        0.590829933159 0.107652704302  5.4882962485 0.0000000897284090545896811496
Dxa10        0.844467615482 0.158884293731  5.3149848588 0.0000002155548361048376260901
Dxb10        0.954943794890 0.211552134711  4.5139879879 0.0000093181083254695419243810
Dxc10        1.085079304770 0.296378110020  3.6611317371 0.0002992055447114028610307301
Dxd10        1.063561741624 0.581825116235  1.8279749566 0.0685986302886704285564078987
Dxe10        1.107517771712 1.600387682825  0.6920309270 0.4894813128833755966340390842
Dxf10        0.455031358074 1.231561429324  0.3694751616 0.7120479544944554595176100520
```

I would like to extract from summary(st1), summary (st2) and summary (st3) the name of the coefficients "Dxd10","Dxc10" etc, that in their respectives column Pr(>|t|) are smaller than 0.1.

I know how to extract the coefficient one by one "summary(st1)$coefficients[2,4]" but not the names.I believe the which function would be effective but have tried without success

Comment: Use rownames around the subsetted matrix of coefficients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lapply(list(st1, st2, st3), function(x) {
  tmp <- coef(summary(x))[, 4] 
  names(tmp)[tmp < 0.1]
})
```

This will return a list of vectors including the names of the coefficients.